# After downloading Ubuntu.img to external drive can I set computer to boot from that drive?

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I'm in the process of downloading ubuntu netbook remix onto an external drive.

**After it's downloaded do I need to do anything to the .img file before I set the computer to boot from that drive?**

**Will the computer automatically know what to do with the .img file when it boots up?**

(The computer is currently Windows XP but I plan to completely reformat the disk and have Ubuntu be the only OS.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, no. You should create a bootable usb drive.

There's a **great** project for this. Is called [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). With a simple graphical interface, you select your img and the program itself creates this bootable usb drive.

It works. I tested in my hp latop running Windows Vista. I use it as a "live cd" alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply load that img file into a virtual drive and run it, Ubuntu can setup from windows. Im not sure for the remix version, give it a try.