# Installing Ubuntu without a bootable CD

Tags: ubuntu, windows-vista, boot

I am currently planning on installing a 64 bit version of Ubuntu. I have my partitions set up already, but my cd writer is currently out of commission. Is there anyway for me to install it without creating a bootable CD?

(My computer is currently dual-booting between Vista x32 and ubuntu x32)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to boot and install from a USB flash drive, if your motherboard supports it and you have a large enough flash drive for the Live CD contents. [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) can help set up the USB drive.

Answer (score 3):

You can install by reading Ubuntu's official guide [from a USB stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick). Check [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/42449/after-downloading-ubuntu-img-to-external-drive-can-i-set-computer-to-boot-from-th/42453#42453) since it's similar to what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have an OS, otherwise use a USB drive.

When having an OS, like Windows, just:

Download the ISO and mount it using a virtual CD-ROM drive software like Virtual CloneDrive.

Now by default the WUBI installer would open with the options you want to install Ubuntu. Yes, you can not delete Windows easily now, but when your CD drive is ready I guess it would.

STILL I SAY IF IT'S POSSIBLE BOOT FROM THE USB STICK!

Comment: Wubi is Ubuntu in windows. Since my windows installation is 32-bit, it defeats the point of installing Ubuntu x64.

Comment: Wubi basically uses Windows boot-loader and NTFS to bootload it self.  It's not a virtualization technology really.  After Ubuntu is loaded, Windows isn't running in the background.  Now if Ubunutu is able to switch to 64bit instruction sets successfully at that point I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You could also bring a laptop and serve the installation over network (you'll have to set up a TFTP server for that), if your NIC can do PXE boot.